# Sort a list of products save in localstorage with JavaScript change event listener

Tags: javascript, html, css, sorting

I have saved a list of products in localstorgae and I want all my products to be displayed in descending order when I click on one of the combobox items

```js
const _UserData = [
    { id: 1, pic: "img/113677817.jpg", title: "کیسه بوکس", price: 159.000 },
    { id: 2, pic: "img/hand.jpg", title: "دستکش بوکس", price: 389.000 },
    { id: 3, pic: "img/hat.jpg", title: "کلاه تکواندو", price: 120.000 },
    { id: 4, pic: "img/tekvando.jpg", title: "لباس کاراته", price: 100.000 },
    { id: 5, pic: "img/nanchico.jpg", title: "نانچیکو", price: 230.500 },
    { id: 6, pic: "img/gel.jpg", title: "محافظ لثه", price: 42.000 },
    { id: 7, pic: "img/hogo.jpg", title: "هوگو تکواندو", price: 150.000 },
    { id: 8, pic: "img/ktg.jpg", title: "نقاب تکواندو", price: 160.000 },
    { id: 9, pic: "img/kongfu.jpg", title: "لباس کنگفو", price: 216.500 },
    { id: 10, pic: "img/band.jpg", title: "کمربند تکواندو", price: 27.000 },
    { id: 11, pic: "img/short.jpg", title: "شورت ووشو", price: 351.000 }
    ];
    
    

newFunction();
console.log(_UserData);

function newFunction() {
    _UserData.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.title.localeCompare(b.title)==-1) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }

    });
}
```

```html
<div class="select d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center m-5">
  <select name="format" id="sort">
    <option selected disabled>جستجو بر اساس</option>
    <option value="dec-price">قیمت-نزولی</option>
    <option value="inc-price">قیمت-صعودی</option>
    <option value="dec-title">عنوان-نزولی</option>
    <option value="inc-title">عنوان-صعودی</option>
  </select>
</div>

> Blockquote
```

Comment: Your sort function could be improved by returning the value of [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). There is an example in the link on how to use it for array sorting. You may also want to include the [language code](https://www.techonthenet.com/js/language_tags.php) for Arabic ("ar") to ensure it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for an answer,
I used the onchange event for the select tag and my problem was solved